# Callback functions finishing in the wrong order

Tags: c#, facebook, entity-framework, callback, facebook-canvas

This is a very confusing issue so I will do my best to elaborate. I have a facebook canvas app that takes payments and when the user hits the payment button, the following happens:

1. My javascript callback function gets called and is passed a payment id and so I save this payment id and other info to my order database.
2. Facebook calls a callback url that I have setup to let me know when the payment goes through. It gives me the payment id only so I use this to search the database for the row with the payment id they have sent. I then use the info in the row to populate an email that I send to the customer for their order confirmation.

My big issue is that for some reason step 2 is getting finished before step 1 so when I try to look up the payment id in the database, it doesn't exist yet so I can't send the email to the customer. What can I do to fix this? I have the pseudo code below for both steps.

Step 1:

```
using (OrderDBContext order = new OrderDBContext())
            {
                string message = Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(orderDetails.request_id, GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppId, 0);
                string[] finalMessage = message.Split('@');
                int orderID = Convert.ToInt16(finalMessage.ElementAtOrDefault(2));
                Models.Order row = order.Orders.Where(i => i.ID == orderID).FirstOrDefault();

                switch (orderDetails.status)
                {
                    case "completed":
                        row.PaymentID = orderDetails.payment_id;
                        row.Currency = orderDetails.currency;
                        row.HashKey = orderDetails.request_id;
                        row.Paid = true;

                        order.SaveChanges();
                        return Json(new { message = "Your payment was processed! You will receive a confirmation email soon." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    case "initiated":
                        row.PaymentID = orderDetails.payment_id;
                        row.Currency = orderDetails.currency;
                        row.HashKey = orderDetails.request_id;
                        row.Paid = false;

                        order.SaveChanges();
                        return Json(new { message = "Your payment is being processed! You will receive a confirmation email as soon as the payment is confirmed." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
```

Step 2:

```
dynamic result = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
                string paymentID;

                if (items.entry != null && items.entry.Count > 0)
                {
                    paymentID = items.entry[0].id;
                }
                else
                {
                    // logic when items.entry is null or doesn't have any elements
                    paymentID = null;
                }

                if (PaymentHelper.confirmPayment(paymentID, GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppId, GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppSecret))
                {
                    // if payment is confirmed then send email to us with the order details
                    // then send confirmation email to user letting them know that we are working on it
                    using (OrderDBContext order = new OrderDBContext())
                    {
                        Order row = order.Orders.Where(i => i.PaymentID == paymentID).FirstOrDefault();
                        SendEmail.sendOrderDetailsToWriter(row);
                        SendEmail.sendOrderDetailsToCustomer(row);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: you need a 3rd step syncing the 2 firsts.

Comment: @tschmit007 not sure what you mean exactly. can you give some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What initiates the Facebook operation? Does something in step #1 cause step #2 to start? Or are both steps started asynchronously and together?

Assuming the latter (since that's the more difficult scenario), you should do something like this:

```
readonly object o = new object();
bool databaseUpdated;

// user clicked the payment button
void onClick()
{
    databaseUpdated = false;

    StartStep1();
    StartStep2();
}

// completion routines for steps #1 and #2
void stepOneDone()
{
    lock (o)
    {
        // do the database update here...i.e. the code you posted for step #1

       databaseUpdated = true;
       Monitor.Pulse(o);
    }
}

void stepTwoDone()
{
    lock (o)
    {
        while (!databaseUpdated)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(o);
        }

        // Process Facebook response here...i.e. the code you posted for step #2
    }
}
```

The above uses a shared lock for the two operations to synchronize with each other. The `databaseUpdated` flag indicates of course whether the database update has completed. If the step #2 completion is initiated before the database update has even managed to start (i.e. step #2 acquires the lock before step #1 can), it will check the flag, note that it's not set yet, and will wait. The call to `Monitor.Wait()` releases the lock so that step #1 can take it. Then step #1 does what it needs to do, sets the flag, and signals to the step #2 thread that it can continue.

Of course if step #1 acquires the lock first, step #2 won't even be able to get it. By the time the lock is available again and step #2 can process past the `lock` statement, the flag will be set and it can go on its merry way. :)

It is possible there's a fun way to solve the problem using the new `async`/`await` idiom, but without more context I can't say. The above should work for sure.

Finally, a minor nit: why do you declare the step #2 `result` variable as `dynamic`? The `ReadToEnd()` method will never return anything except a `string`. The use of `dynamic` here is pointless at best, and potentially extra overhead at worst, due to the dynamic binding required (depending on whether the C# compiler notices it's pointless…I don't recall off the top of my head what the compilation rules are there).

Comment: The user initiates the steps by clicking on the payment button and step 1 is initiated immediately after the payment window is closed but step 2 is essentially up to Facebook because they start a post to the callback when the payment is completed on their end. In my local debugging step 1 always goes through first but when I go through facebook directly to view how the app is working, step 2 always goes through first. I hope this gives you the context you need.

Comment: Did you try applying the technique I describe above? If not, you should. If you did, did it work? If not, you should describe in detail why not.

Comment: I haven't yet. I'm about to try it now. I just wanted to answer your questions first

Comment: How do I do this code if both steps are in different classes and the callback url is part of the same code solution but is pinged on the server side only

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand what you mean. Dealing with the completion routines being in two different classes is simple: they just have to share some synchronization object (e.g. the initiating code can pass the object to both, instead of it being declared as a `readonly object` field). But the second part of your question seems to imply that the two steps are not even being processed on the same machine. I don't understand the terms `callback url` and `pinged on the server side`. :(

Answer (score 1):

in pseudo code:

```
Semaphore = 0;

function Step1() {
    //do your stuff
    Semaphore++;
}

function Step2() {
    //do your stuff
    Semaphore++;
}

function Step3() {
    while (1) { // for example a setTimer in javascript
        if ( Semaphore >= 2 ) {
            // send email
            break;
        } 
        if ( timeout() ) {
            // send error message
            break;
        }
        sleep(200);
    }
}

Step1.Start();
Step2.Start();
Step3.Start();
```

you may certainly find a javascript framework allowing to sync two tasks. Here it is a really simple and naive syncing.